# Instead of setting height:100%; can I just go height:2000px;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have col-sm-1 and col-sm-9 and col-sm-3. I want them to have a full height. When I do height:100%, the height goes full only when I have contents inside them. I want the height to be full even when it's just empty.
So I just did `height:2000px; background-color:grey;` and now this looks like the way I want. However even a beginner like me know this isn't the best way to do it. 
Am I allowed to go height:2000px; and deal with it?

Comment: Look into flexbox instead, or display: table

Comment: @ScottSimpson I tried both, but the height only goes 100% if there's a content

Comment: I like to use 100vh along with the viewport tag

Comment: @MrEhawk82 100vh does same thing....I must set up something wrong maybe...only thing that works is setting height=largenumber px;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Assign their parent a class `.flexbox`, set the CSS as below.

```
.flexbox .col {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile, and donot remember something from the URL markdown, that's why the reference URL is breaking up, somebody please fix it.

Comment: @mike braa Cool :)

Comment: by the way if I use 100vh for such issue, will I run into a problem in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The height 100% fills the space even if the content isn't there but it may be not working just due to parent container height is not set. So, for this you need to define the parent element height in fixed pixel or set 100% height parent-hierarchy way. In short you can fix this problem by just setting the height 100% to the `html,body`:

```
html,body{
  height: 100%;
}
.your_element{
  height: 100%;
}
```

And here is a demo:

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  }
div{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div>some content</div>
```

Comment: I just tried it but it does same thing, the height doesn't stretch out

Comment: hmmm I must be doing something wrong, I set html and body like you said and col-sm-1 as my element

Comment: will I run into problem if I just set height to really large number?

Comment: @mikebraa you have to define a height on all of the parent elements of the element you are targeting.